# Derivative of $a^TA(x)^{-1}b$ with respect to x

Tags: matrix-calculus

Let's say $a$ and $b$ are $n$ by $1$ vectors and $A(x)$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix that depends on scalar parameter $x$. I would like to take derivative of
$$\frac{da^TA(x)^{-1}b}{dx}.$$

I know that
$$\frac{da^TA^{-1}b}{dA} = - A^{-T}ab^T A^{-T}$$
from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023692/derivative-of-inverse-matrix-by-itself).

But I could not derive the result I want.

Comment: $D \operatorname{inv}(A)H = - A^{-1} H A^{-1}$.

Comment: @copper.hat what are $D$ and $H$?

Comment: It is the derivative of the inverse at $A$ applied to the 'perturbation' $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\A{A^{-1}}
\def\At{A^{-T}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\Dx#1{\frac{d #1}{dx}}
\def\DxLR#1{\LR{\Dx{#1}}}
$Take the known gradient of the function $\:\phi = {a^T\A b}$
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{A} &= -\At ab^T\At \qquad\qquad\quad \\
}$$
and rewrite it as a differential (using a [double-dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Product_of_dyadic_and_dyadic) product)
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= -\LR{\At ab^T\At}: dA \quad\; \\
}$$
then as a derivative with respect to the scalar $x$
$$\eqalign{
\Dx\phi &= -\LR{\At ab^T\At}: \DxLR A \\
}$$
then rearrange it into a simpler form
$$\eqalign{
\Dx\phi &= -a^T\A\DxLR A\A b \qquad \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Such single variable derivatives can be easily computed from first principles using [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) as an [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Automatic_differentiation_using_dual_numbers) tool.  Write $$\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} = A’$$ so the dual expansion of $A$ is $A + A’ \varepsilon$.  Here $\varepsilon$ can be treated as a scalar for matrix- and vector multiplication.

To find $(A + A’ \varepsilon)^{-1}$ solve $$1 = (A + A’ \varepsilon)(A^{-1} + B \varepsilon) = 1 + (A B + A’ A^{-1}) \varepsilon$$ for $B$. This gives $$(A + A’ \varepsilon)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1} A’  A^{-1} \varepsilon.$$

Now $a$ and $b$ are constant in $x$ so the dual expansion of your function is $$a^{\mathrm t}(A^{-1} - A^{-1} A’ A^{-1} \varepsilon) b = a^{\mathrm t} A^{-1} b - a^{\mathrm t} A^{-1} A’ A^{-1} b \varepsilon.$$

The $\varepsilon$ coefficient in this expression gives the derivative $$- a^{\mathrm t} A^{-1} A’ A^{-1} b.$$